# Linux Safety/Security : Is Linux safe if its source code is open?

Tags: kernel, security, open-source

I am new to Linux and thinking about safety.

I know that Linux is more safe than other operating systems, but why? If it is open source, then anyone can make changes in the kernel. So what if someone implements unsafe source code in the kernel? Is there anybody who checks this?

Comment: This is too broad for a question. And "more safe" is opinion based.

Answer (score 3):

It is safe ***because*** it is open source, not despite the fact. Think about this -- algorithms used for things like password encryption are well-known. This way, the community as a whole can examine the algorithm and confirm its security.

Of course there are many topics on which people can become very opinionated with regard to security. So the answer you get might depend on who you ask.

> If it is opensource system that all people can make change in kernel.

People can contribute and submit patches, but there are still checks and balances and a core developer team that reviews and tests code before it's checked in. A person assigned to review a submitted patch is typically an expert in the niche that the code affects.

There are a lot of distributions out there, too. If a change is made to Ubuntu, that is not necessarily mean that other distros adopt the same changes. I recommend looking into the open source process in general and learning more about typical workflows.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Linux community!

Despite the question is too wide and opinion based, I would like to give you few points.
Everyone can participate in creating linux - that's true. But no single change is ever published without being approved and triple-checked and tested.

Ubuntu, and many others linux distribution, uses repositories, which can be official, or third-party, also called unsupported. You can obtain potentially harmful piece of software only from this third-party repositories or compile it by yourself. But there are thousands of users and developers, which would immediately flag repository as fake or harmful, so there is really nothing to worry about.
What is more, no one (maybe Micro$oft) is really interest in harming linux users (at least not this way), because we are still minority and it's really really hard to actually get working malicious code to your machine.

I hope you got your answer. If you are more interested in linux, there are thousands of pages around the Internet. Also, if you want to know some background, I recommend this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ocq6_3-nEw

---